# Disabling menu items using other winform (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi I have a problem with my code: I have two windows form **Menu** and **Login**. I set **Menu** as MdiParent.

So this is what it looks like.

[image]

My problem is when I log in as Clerk I want User Account to be disbled. My code in **Login** Form is this:

```
    If myReader.Read Then
       MsgBox("Log-in Successfully", vbInformation, "Log-in")
       If cmbtype.Text = "Clerk" Then
           Menu.useracc.Enabled = False 'but i got an error here
       Else
           Menu.useracc.Enabled = True  'same as here
       End If
       Me.Close()
       clear()
    Else
      MsgBox("Username and Password do not match. Please check and log-in again.", vbCritical, "Log-in Failed")
   End If
```

> What would be the right code to disable menu item from my **Menu Form** when **Login Form** closes.

Comment: _but i got an error here_ do you mind to tell us the error message?

Comment: Error 1 'useracc' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu'.

Comment: Then check if there is a MenuItem with that name and fix the name or change the name used in your code.

Comment: You don't need to change menu from your login form. Instead you need to notify the `MenuForm` of the logged in username or role and then apply changes on menu. For example you can have a public `UserName` or `Role` property in your `LoginForm`. Then after showing login form using `ShowDialog`, you can use that property in your `MenuForm` to change menu appearance.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I'll try it.

Comment: I got it guys. I played around the vb.net and i got the answer to my question.

in properties of the menuitems **Modifiers** >then make it  **Public**